# What does 'snap "opera" has "remove-snap" change in progress' mean and how do I stop it?

Tags: 18.04, snap, software-uninstall, opera

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and the following message is showing after I tried to delete the Opera browser from my device:

```
status code=409,kind=snap-change-conflict message=snap"opera" has "opera" has "remove-snap" change in progress
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you see a "change in progress" message it means that Snap is working on something in the background. You can get a list of what's going on in the Terminal like this:

```
snap changes
```

If Snap does have something going on, then you'll see a message like:

```
123  Doing   2021-05-06T00:00:00Z  -  Remove "opera" snap
```

Otherwise, you'll see:

```
error: no changes found
```

If you need to abort a Snap change, you can do this:

```
sudo snap abort {ID}
```

**Note:** `{ID}` is found in the result of `snap changes`.

Comment: .... what can one do if the abort command returns, but still the change is shown?