# How can I force remove a snap

Tags: snap

I am trying to delete Spotify.

I ran `sudo snap remove spotify`, but it hung for a long time and I had to kill the command by sending it a SIGQUIT (`Ctrl` + `\`) since it didn't respond with a SIQINT (`Ctrl` + `c`)

I tried running the command again but its now in this weird stuck state where it says it's installed but cannot be removed.

Here is some diagnostic information:

```
$ snap changes
ID   Status  Spawn               Ready               Summary
153  Done    today at 16:15 CDT  today at 16:16 CDT  Auto-refresh snap "spotify"
154  Error   today at 21:35 CDT  today at 21:44 CDT  Remove "spotify" snap
155  Abort   today at 21:44 CDT  -                   Remove "spotify" snap
```

```
$ sudo snap install spotify
snap "spotify" is already installed, see 'snap help refresh'
```

```
$ sudo snap refresh spotify
snap "spotify" has no updates available
```

```
$ sudo snap remove --purge spotify
error: snap "spotify" has "remove-snap" change in progress
```

I tried googling but I can't find anything about forcefully removing the snap.

How do I force snap to delete this snap?

Comment: You will need to first [abort the change in progress](https://askubuntu.com/a/1336401/1222991), then issue another `remove` 

Comment: That worked. If you respond to the question, I will mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Just upvoting the linked answer is sufficient, as this is essentially a duplicate question 

Comment: @matigo I think this is a different question and deserves its own answer. You can copy paste your comment to your answer to this question. Comments are often overlooked and having no answers gives the wrong impression the question is unanswered.